# Measure Theory Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I was having trouble showing the following inequality:

Prove that if $A \subset I = [0,1]$ has measure $u(A) < 1$ and $\epsilon > 0$, then there is an interval $[a,b] \subset I$ such that $u(A \cap [a,b]) < \epsilon(b-a)$. (Where $u$ denotes Lebesgue Measure)

I was thinking of showing that the set $I \setminus A$ contains an interval $[a,b]$ but you cannot necessarily show this because $I/A$ can be a set such as the irrationals.

Otherwise I'm not sure where to begin. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can find an open set $O$   containing $I\setminus A$ with $\mu  (A\cap O)<\mu(I\setminus A)\epsilon $. Note $O$ can be written as a disjoint union of countably many non-degenerate open intervals. Show that your inequality holds for at least one of these intervals.

Comment: How do you justify that such an $O$ exists?

Comment: Lebesgue measure is a [regular measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularity_theorem_for_Lebesgue_measure).

Comment: Thanks +1 for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

By [Lebesgue's density theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue's_density_theorem), for almost every point $x$ in $I-A$, we have $$\lim_{\delta \to 0}\dfrac{\mu((I-A)\cap[x-\delta, x+\delta])}{2\delta} = 1$$ and $$\mu((I-A)\cap[x-\delta, x+\delta]) = 2\delta -\mu(A\cap [x-\delta, x+\delta]) $$ which gives $$\lim_{\delta \to 0}\dfrac{\mu(A\cap [x-\delta, x+\delta])}{2\delta} = 0$$

Comment: Ah I see, thanks!

Comment: @JJTJP you are welcome!